# How many times has my app been downloaded from the Microsoft store

Tags: windows, store

As a developer, how can I see how many times my app has been downloaded from the Microsoft store?  I'm logged into the Microsoft Partner Centre, and I see my submission but it gives me no useful information whatsoever.  I'm hoping that I'm just looking in the wrong place, though considering how awful this entire experience has been with the Partner Centre, perhaps I'm expecting too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Partner center click your app. In the next window just click "View analytics reports" and have a look at "Acquisitions"